# If...else if Confusion C++

Tags: c++

I am having great confusion while working with if/else statements, i have constructed a program to decide which of three provided integers is the maximum... i wrote the following code:

```
int a,b,c,max;

cout<<"Please enter value 1: \t";
cin>>a;

cout<<"Please enter value 2: \t";
cin>>b;

cout<<"Please enter value 3: \t";
cin>>c;

if(a>b)
    {
    if(a>c)
    max=a;
        }


else if(b>a)
    {
    if(b>c)
    max=b;
    }

else if(c>a)                 //here comes the problem
    {
    if(c>b)
    max=c;
    }

cout<<"The Max value among the given value is:\t"<<max;
```

I inputted the values 12 for int a, 13 for int b, and 14 for int c, (meaning if i am providing largest value at third instance) it is showing me a garbage value as the maximum (in spite of 14), what might be the problem there please???? I am using Dev C++ 5.5.1 On 32 bit windows 7.

Comment: If you format your code properly then the logic is much easier to follow.

Comment: Something called as "Debugger" is of great help when such situations arrive,try using it

Comment: The logic is just faulty and you should read some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And easier and more readable construct would be like this:

```
int maximum(int a, int b, int c) {
    int max = a; 

    if (b > max) { 
        max = b;
    }

    if (c > max) { 
        max = c;
    } 

    return max; 
}
```

or even shorter

```
    if (a>= b&& a>= c)
            cout << "The largest number is：" << a<< endl;
    else if (b> =a&& b> =c)
            cout << "The largest number is：" << b<< endl;
    else if (c>= a&& c> =b)
            cout << "The largest number is：" << c<< endl;
```

Comment: Or even shorter : `max = a > b ? (a > c ? a : c) : (b > c ? b : c) ;`

Comment: what if I want to do this with if...else only?

Comment: Or even shorter with STL: `const int max = std::max(std::max(a, b), c);`

Comment: Hmmmm. Yes guys there's the logical problem, got it... thank you all for replying

Comment: @blackbird Or even shorter with C++11: `const int max = std::max({a, b, c});` because `std::max` has an overload that takes an `initializer_list`.

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple matter of formatting your code properly, including:

- aligning `{` and `}` properly
- being consistent with indentation

---

```
int a,b,c,max;

cout<<"Please enter value 1: \t";
cin>>a;

cout<<"Please enter value 2: \t";
cin>>b;

cout<<"Please enter value 3: \t";
cin>>c;

if(a>b) {
    if(a>c)
        max=a;
} else if(b>a) {
    if(b>c)
        max=b;
} else if(c>a) {
    if(c>b)
        max=c;
}

cout<<"The Max value among the given value is:\t"<<max;
```